# Angular input no border-bottom after router.navigate

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a big form on a `ContactFormComponent.ts` (with route : `index.php?#/administration/contacts/list/XX` and I had to make a redirection from `HomeComponent.ts` (with route `index.php?#/home`) to `ContactFormComponent.ts`

I use this command :

```
this.router.navigate([`/administration/contacts/list/${row.contact_id}`])
```

But my input are weirs after, there is no border-bottom...

Before : [image]

After : [image]

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if `${row.contact_id}` in the command is not yielding a valid value in your scenario.

Try testing using some hard coded value in the command:

`this.router.navigate(['/administration/contacts/list/12'])`